# Running function in split windows in wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, splitter

I'm trying to use `wx.SplitterWindow` to split my main window into three pieces: one top window and two bottom windows (the bottom windows are left bottom and right bottom).

Here is what I have and what I am experiencing:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import wxmplot
import wx
import os

class topPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        #self.SetBackgroundColour("red")

class bottomLeft(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    def plotWaves(self,parent):
        self.figureWave = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figureWave.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figureWave)
        t = [ 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
        s = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0]
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        self.sizerWave = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizerWave.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizerWave)
        self.Fit()

########################################################################

class bottomRight(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    def plotMAW(self,parent):

        self.figureMAW = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figureMAW.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figureMAW)
        #self.axes.plot(self.waves)
        t = [ 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
        s = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0]
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        self.sizerMAW = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizerMAW.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizerMAW)
        self.Fit()


########################################################################

### SETUP GUI HERE
 class myGUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "myGUI", size=(850,500))

        # DEFINE A SPLIT WINDOW FOR PLOTTING
        self.splitWin = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        topP = topPanel(self)
        bottomPLeft = bottomLeft(self.splitWin)
        bottomPRight = bottomRight(self.splitWin)

        # SPLIT THE WINDOW
        self.splitWin.SplitVertically(bottomPLeft, bottomPRight)
        self.splitWin.SetMinimumPaneSize(350)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(topP, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.splitWin, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.control = p = wx.Panel(self, 1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        # SETUP CONFIG WINDOW
        self.result = wx.StaticText(p, label="")
        self.result.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self, label="Config File:")
        self.editname = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(140, -1))

        # Set sizer for the panel content
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.lblname, (1, 2))
        self.sizer.Add(self.editname, (1, 3))

        # SETUP RUN MENU
        runMenu = wx.Menu()  # create a menu for running DAQ
        runConfig = runMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "&Configure", "Load configuration file")
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(runMenu, "&Run")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onConfigure, runConfig)

        self.Show(1)
        self.aboutme = wx.MessageDialog( self, " A sample editor \n"
                            " in wxPython","About Sample Editor", wx.OK)
        self.doiexit = wx.MessageDialog( self, " Exit - R U Sure? \n",
                        "GOING away ...", wx.YES_NO)
        self.dirname = ''
    def onConfigure(self,e):
    # Load specific configuration file for system being used

        openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", "", "",
                                   "Python files (*.py)|*.py",
                                   wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
        if openFileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename=openFileDialog.GetFilename()
            self.dirname=openFileDialog.GetDirectory()
            filehandle=open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename),'r')
            self.configName = self.filename[:-3]
            filehandle.close()
        lP = bottomLeft(self)
        lP.plotWaves(self)
        rP = bottomRight(self)
        rP.plotMAW(self)
        self.editname.AppendText(self.configName)
        openFileDialog.Destroy()

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = myGUI()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This is a complete example of my GUI and if you run the configure menu and load any file (it doesn't matter because that is just to run the def plotWaves and def plotMAW functions) you will see that the plots overtake the GUI. If you comment out the lines `def plotWaves(self,parent):` and `def plotMAW(self,parent):` then the plots appear in the correct place. The first image shows the result if you comment out the definition lines. The second image shows the result if you do NOT comment them out.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you trying to overwrite the items that are already loaded into the splitter window.
Try this instead:
Note: I have no idea what `wxmplot` is, so I've commented it out

```
from __future__ import print_function
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
#import wxmplot
import wx
import os

class topPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        #self.SetBackgroundColour("red")

class bottomLeft(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    def plotWaves(self):
        self.figureWave = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figureWave.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figureWave)
        t = [ 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
        s = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0]
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        self.sizerWave = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizerWave.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizerWave)
        self.Fit()

########################################################################

class bottomRight(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    def plotMAW(self):

        self.figureMAW = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figureMAW.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figureMAW)
        #self.axes.plot(self.waves)
        t = [ 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
        s = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0]
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        self.sizerMAW = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizerMAW.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizerMAW)
        self.Fit()


########################################################################

### SETUP GUI HERE
class myGUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "myGUI", size=(850,500))

        # DEFINE A SPLIT WINDOW FOR PLOTTING
        self.splitWin = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        topP = topPanel(self)
        self.lp = bottomLeft(self.splitWin)
        self.rp = bottomRight(self.splitWin)

        # SPLIT THE WINDOW
        self.splitWin.SplitVertically(self.lp, self.rp)
        self.splitWin.SetMinimumPaneSize(350)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(topP, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.splitWin, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.control = p = wx.Panel(self, 1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        # SETUP CONFIG WINDOW
        self.result = wx.StaticText(p, label="")
        self.result.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self, label="Config File:")
        self.editname = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(140, -1))

        # Set sizer for the panel content
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.lblname, (1, 2))
        self.sizer.Add(self.editname, (1, 3))

        # SETUP RUN MENU
        runMenu = wx.Menu()  # create a menu for running DAQ
        runConfig = runMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "&Configure", "Load configuration file")
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(runMenu, "&Run")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onConfigure, runConfig)

        self.Show(1)
        self.aboutme = wx.MessageDialog( self, " A sample editor \n"
                            " in wxPython","About Sample Editor", wx.OK)
        self.doiexit = wx.MessageDialog( self, " Exit - R U Sure? \n",
                        "GOING away ...", wx.YES_NO)
        self.dirname = ''

    def onConfigure(self,e):
    # Load specific configuration file for system being used

        openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", "", "",
                                   "Python files (*.py)|*.py",
                                   wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
        if openFileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename=openFileDialog.GetFilename()
            self.dirname=openFileDialog.GetDirectory()
            filehandle=open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename),'r')
            self.configName = self.filename[:-3]
            filehandle.close()
        self.lp.plotWaves()
        self.rp.plotMAW()
        self.editname.AppendText(self.configName)
        openFileDialog.Destroy()
        self.Refresh()

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = myGUI()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you for showing me how to solve this problem!